# Scrape background-images using X-Ray-Scraper

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, x-ray

I've been using X-Ray to scrape website which has been working really well. I can use it bring in images very easily. The one item I run into is I don't see an easy way to scrape a background image. Say I have a div where they are setting a style attribute on that dev and then setting the URL im not sure how to get the background-image url from this. I don't think I can just pass the featured image attribute the css property such as

```
 .featured-image.attr('background-image');

const getWebsiteContent = async (blogURL, selector) => {
  try {
    return await x(blogURL, selector, [{
      slug: 'a@href',
      featuredImage: 'img@src'
   }])
   .paginate(`${pagi}@href`)
   .limit(200)
   .then((response) => {
   spinner.succeed('Got the data');
   return response;
  })
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error('Cannot get Data from website, try checking your URL');
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants a solution to this with X-ray scraper what I ended up doing is pulling the attribute from the selector you pass into the object.Given the html looks like the following.

```
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('../path-to-img.jpg')"></div>
```

Instead of writing `.img@src` you could write `.img@style` and this would return to you the style attribute. From there you would need to use a regex to remove the rest of the un-needed data that is not the URL of the image.